# Add one github repo to the other

Tags: git, github

How do I add existing github repos to a new repo? This is not "merge" as my intention is to add files from an existing repo into a new repo preserving the folder structure and history of all files.

I have 3 different repos

```
github.com/foo/1.git
github.com/foo/2.git
github.com/foo/3.git
```

Each of them have a set of folders and files.

I am creating something new called 4 (github.com/foo/4.git) where I want to add the existing repos.

I did something like this:

```
git clone github.com/foo/4.git
git clone github.com/foo/1.git
cd 4
git remote add 1 ../1
git fetch 1
git branch 1-master 1/master
git merge 1-master
```

After I commit, what I found was that files and folders from 1 were directly copied into 4.

Let's say I have abc.txt under 1, then I ended up seeing abc.txt under 4.

What I really want to see is 4/1/abc.txt than 4/abc.txt with the history of abc.txt preserved.

How do I do this?

On a side note, I read this article before I started working on adding: http://blog.caplin.com/2013/09/18/merging-two-git-repositories/

Comment: You're looking for submodules.

Comment: What I really want is add files from 1,2,3 one time into 4 with history preserved and later delete 1,2,3. How do I do it? Not sure if submodules help me here as I believe they are just pointers to 1,2,3.

Answer (score 0):

You want to merge in the full histories of the other repos, but after rewriting them to move their entire histories into subfolders.

That's what [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) is for.

For each subrepo:

1. Clone the subrepo
2. `git filter-branch --tree-filter "mv * dir/"
3. Add the clone as a remote of the master repo
4. Fetch that remote
5. `git merge` or (if you want to rewrite the master's history too) `git rebase` the fetched (and already-rewritten) remote into the master's main branch.